# Django Form - Render Form changing hiddenInput Value in the template

Tags: python, django, forms, templates, django-templates

After I defined MyForm in the forms.py with a HiddenInput with dummy value, I want to render as forms as users I've in my database and with username as hidden input.

Template Django:

```
{% for username,time in llistat_usuaris.items %}

{{ form.as_p }} # HOW CAN I SET {{USERNAME}} as hidden value ??

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Why not just give form initial values when initializing the form?

Comment: You should not do that in the template but rather use the Forms to do that. In your case maybe even a FormSet is useful.

Comment: @OdifYltsaeb Is a bad idea I think because I don't know how many users I have and how many forms I have to render in my view

Comment: @toabi Could you give me an example?

Comment: @user3584455 Well, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/formsets/ - As I don't know what exactly you want to achieve and how your data is structured, it's hard to tell what's the best.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this ?

```
{{ form.field.as_hidden }}
```

".as_hidden" this makes any form field to be invisible to the users, but you receive the field in the post as others

I usually create a field like a normal field, and in the template I add "as_hidden", so django won't display this field in the browser.

I suggest you to check this posts:

[Hidden Field in Django model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086267/hidden-field-in-django-model)

[Django forms hidden model field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686858/django-forms-hidden-model-field)

[Django ModelForm to have a hidden input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795869/django-modelform-to-have-a-hidden-input)

But if you want to get the username of the user who makes the post, is easier than that, you only need to access the request.user

Comment: I want a way to call a view with a dynamic argument, the argument is the selected username

Comment: What is exactly what you're trying to do ? You can pass arguments from different ways: post, get, request, session, middleware... My problem is I don't understand what is exactly what you're trying to do

Comment: What you're trying to do is to change the value of hidden input username in the template?